# How to do RLE (run length encoding) in C# on a byte array?

Tags: c#

I am trying to XOR two bitmap files (their byte arrays) to produce a byte array that can be used to change image A into image B or vice versa.  I am sending this over the network so I would like to do some basic compression before this happens.

Is there a way to do RLE (run length encoding) in C# (using a built-in, or fast reliable 3rd party library) on a byte array for this purpose?

Notes:

- If you are going to suggest an alternative to my approach please keep in mind that the decompression and transformation on the remote machine has to be as quick and efficient as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use GZipStream. It's fast enough and works fine.

```
class Compressor
{
    public static byte[] compress(byte[] buffer)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
        zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        zip.Close();
        ms.Position = 0;

        byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

        byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
        return gzBuffer;
    }
    public static byte[] decompress(byte[] gzBuffer)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
        ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];

        ms.Position = 0;
        GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "outStream" used for in the Compress method?

Comment: Actually "outStream" is pretty useless. I just copied the code myself a while ago and did not check it in detail. Of course you can delete the line containing the definition of "outStream". Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two methods of RLE string packing/unpacking. The best result will be seen on a big text.

```
    public string PackText()
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder(Text);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            char ch;
            int i, k, j;
            for (i = 0; i < str1.Length; ) // from 0 to length of unpackedtext
            {
                ch = str1[i]; // get current char from str1
                k = 0; //count the number of repeated characters
                if (i == str1.Length - 1) // If this is the last character
                {
                    str.Append(ch);
                    break; //exit the loop
                }

                if (str1[i + 1] == ch) //if current symbol is next
                {
                    for (j = i; j < str1.Length; j++) //packing the characters
                    {
                        if (str1[j] == ch) //if current symbol is next
                        {
                            if (k == 9) break; //the maximum number of characters packed 9, 
                            //or there might be problems with unpacking is not packed numeric characters
                            k++;

                        }
                        else break;
                    }
                    i = j;
                }
                else if ("0123456789".Contains(ch)) //if this digit and it is not repeated, then it must be escaped,
                    //so when unpacking to understand that this is not the number of repeated characters
                {
                    k = 1;
                    i++;
                }
                else i++;


                if (k != 0)
                    str.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", k, ch); //forming packed string
                else
                    str.Append(ch);

            }
            return str.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string UnpackText()
    {
        try
        {

            StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder(Text);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            char ch;
            char symb = 'a';
            int s = 0;
            int i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < str1.Length; ) // from 0 to length of packedtext
            {
                ch = str1[i]; // get current char from str1
                s = 0;
                if ("123456789".Contains(ch)) //if this digit
                {
                    if (i == str1.Length - 1) // If this is the last character
                    {
                        symb = ch;
                        s = 1;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        symb = str1[i + 1]; // get packed symbol
                        i += 2;
                        s = Convert.ToInt32(ch) - 48; //get the number of repetitions
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    s = 0;
                    i++;
                }
                if (s > 0)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < s; j++) // write the decompressed symbol
                        str.Append(symb);
                }
                else
                    str.Append(ch);
            }
          return  str.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The question was about compressing a _byte_ array, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RLE encoding/decoding tool from CodePlex: http://rle.codeplex.com/ ( C# )

You may build as .net dll and its lib