# How to count the number of times every character is repeated in a string

Tags: c#

How do you count the number of times every character is repeated in a string C#?

For example:

```
string a ="aaabbee"
```

Would result in the following string:

```
"3a2b2e"
```

I looked around and found that this is called [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) and there are existing answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888735/477420 that show how to do that. But it is complicated and uses `StringBuilder` that I don't really need to use.

Comment: What if the characters are not adjacent? i.e. "aaabbaaee"?

Comment: Any attempt? For the data provided, where the runs of the character to count are adjacent, a single loop with a counter variable is sufficient.

Comment: it will be the same string br= "3A2b2a2e";

Comment: So the question is not accurate. You want to count the number of repetitions of characters that are adjacent to each other.

Comment: @sam - Here's how you could do it just with counting repetition: `string br = String.Concat(a.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => $"{x.Count()}{x.Key}"));`. But this doesn't do the new requirement.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i mean

Comment: And a simple loop and counter will “just work”..

Comment: @Enigmativity it works but not with the second requirement

Comment: ..as a simple loop would have worked. Could probably have written it by now. The things to keep track of are the count and character changes. On a character change emit the count and old character. Repeat for all the input. Make sure to emit the last character and counter too as the end of the input is an implicit change.

Comment: Furthermore, the only state required is the counter and i, as the previous (i - 1) character can always be referred to as an indicator of change. The loop could also start at i = 1 for simplicity.

Comment: @sam - Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @Enigmativity you know the answer for the second requirement?

Comment: For some strange reasons duplicate shows exactly the code you asking for even it talks about bytes... https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888735/477420

Comment: Not a very great duplicate question, although one of the answers (that doesn’t actually answer the question) does provides an implementation of the algorithm described above..

Comment: @user2864740 I'm somewhat confused - to me it looks like OP asks for RLE compression. The answer I found shows how to do that (and actual answer showing RLE produces exactly what OP's assignment requires). You may want to [edit] question to clarify what is being asked (as there are plenty of comments to do so). At this point I'm not sure how that is not duplicate.

Comment: The linked **question** is not the same _despite the title_. An _answer_ supplied, is relevant. However, as noted as comment on that answer - it doesn’t pertain to _that_ question, which is not really a duplicate of _this_ question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - There's a magnitude of complexity or two on the linked answer. My eyes glazed over. For the OP it's not a duplicate - it would be enough to put them off of programming.

Comment: @Enigmativity your answer will put everyone off programming so :) I can't decide if it should be upvoted for being unreadable or downvoted for the same :)

Comment: I've edited question so it is clearly not duplicate...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Fair enough. Michael Randall's answer is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I like the code of @Michael Randall, I see some things that can be improved

- it crashes on empty input
- uses interpolation when `StringBuilder` is available. This means 2x slower code than it has to be.
- first loop is always unnecessary
- code of output is duplicated

The altered code may look like this

```
public static string Get22(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return input;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i, start;

    void outP()
    {
        sb.Append(i - start).Append(input[start]);
    }
    
    for (i = 1, start = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != input[start])
        {
            outP();
            start = i;
        }
    }

    outP();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Flaws are addressed, but the code starts to be a bit clumsy. I compared it to another approach. At cost of duplicating termination condition, we get rid of duplicated output code and crashing on empty input with just code structure. Measured speed was exactly the same in my case and the code is quite compact. I see it as an interesting option.

```
public static string Get3(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int start = 0, i = 1; i <= input.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (i == input.Length || input[i] != input[start])
        {
            sb.Append(i - start).Append(input[start]);
            start = i;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple approach would be to use `StringBuilder` or an *iterator* method

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Get(string input)
{
    int i, start;
    for (i = 0, start = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
      if (input[i] != input[start])
      {
         yield return $"{i - start}{input[start]}";
         start = i;
      }
    yield return $"{i - start}{input[start]}";
}
```

or

```
public static string Get2(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i, start;
    for (i = 0, start = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (input[i] != input[start])
        {
            sb.Append($"{i - start}{input[start]}");
            start = i;
        }

    sb.Append($"{i - start}{input[start]}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = string.Concat(Get("xaaabbccaadddd"));
Console.WriteLine(result);

Console.WriteLine(Get2("xaaabbccaadddd"));
```

**Output**

```
1x3a2b2c2a4d
1x3a2b2c2a4d
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUpxLd)

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit ugly, but it works:

```
string br =
    a
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            a.Take(1).Select(x => new { x, c = 1 }).ToList(),
            (q, x) =>
            {
                if (q.Last().x == x)
                {
                    q[q.Count - 1] = new { x, c = q.Last().c + 1 };
                }
                else
                {
                    q.Add(new { x, c = 1 });
                }
                return q;
            }, w => String.Concat(w.Select(e => $"{e.c}{e.x}")));
```

If I start with `"aaabbaaee"` I get `"3a2b2a2e"` out.

---

I appreciate that my answer so far was ugly. Here's an attempt to make it more saleable.

Here's a nice extension method to make these things easier.

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<R> AggregateScan<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, R> intial, Func<R, T, bool> build, Func<R, T, R> builder)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = intial(enumerator.Current);
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (build(current, enumerator.Current))
                {
                    current = builder(current, enumerator.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return current;
                    current = intial(enumerator.Current);
                }
            }
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can do this:

```
string br =
    String.Concat(
        a
            .AggregateScan(
                character => new { character, count = 1 },
                (accumulator, character) => accumulator.character == character,
                (accumulator, character) => new { character, count = accumulator.count + 1 })
            .Select(x => $"{x.count}{x.character}"));
```

Comment: A simple loop would be less ugly here, more efficient, and also work..

Comment: Yes, but less fun.

Comment: Okay, so more copy’n’paste SO code.. I would reject this in a PR. The OP is likely entirely confused. A standard algorithm approach, as one might encounter in a CS101.. whatever, ramen.

Comment: @user2864740 - I agree. Michael Randall's answer is much better.

Comment: I don’t why the downvotes though, as it does shown _a_ working approach and contains useful information, should someone want not to just have a copy’n’paste answer.

Answer (score -2):

No idea why you wouldn't use a simple loop and dictionary here:

```
string text = "aaabbee";
Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach (var character in text)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(character))
    {
        dict[character]++;
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(character, 1);
    }
}
```

`dict` would result in character-count pairs. You could iterate over the dictionary:

```
string text = "aaabbee";
Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach (var character in text)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(character))
    {
        dict[character]++;
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(character, 1);
    }
}
string output = "";
foreach (var result in dict)
{
    output += result.Value + result.Key;
}
```

Of course, this is inefficient as you're iterating twice. However, if you want a simple solution, this is it for you.

Comment: I don't think this would work for the case where the characters aren't adjacent such as "aaabbaacc". OP mentioned in the comments that that should result in "3a2b2a2c".